# SPWorkflowActivationProperties Object Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I'm programatically creating a subsite based on a list item. I need to access the `SPWorkflowActivationProperties` object in order to get the `Site`, `Web` and `Item` fields.

So I've created my workflow and created a class and now I need to access the properties, but I am unsure how. Is there an easy way to access the workflow object that I have overlooked? Or am I supposed to create my methods within in the workflow class? Trying to learn this the proper way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them via a dependency property declared in your custom activity. The web, list, list item information is accessible either via the `__ActivationProperties` (of type [`SPWorkflowActivationProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowactivationproperties.aspx)) or via the `__Context` (of type [`WorkflowContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.workflowcontext_members.aspx)) property.

You can find a tutorial how to declare and use them [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/09/30/getting-to-workflow-information.aspx).